# Read/Explore solution zip file for components in CRM 2011

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there any tool available to read or explore the solution components using solution file?

OR

Is there any class in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK which take the solution zip file as input and then I can simply use its properties/methods to read/validate the contents and components of the solution file?

Answer (score 0):

For validation, there are several schema files within the SDK, one of them being the CustomizationsSolution.xsd

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004

For reading the web resources, you can look directly within the "WebResources" folder or by scanning the "solution.xml" file.

Both of these will require unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [SolutionPackager.Exe tool in the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602987%28v=crm.6%29.aspx) that will take an exported solution file and expand it out to directory with all of its components in separate files. I don't believe it has a public interface to call from other code - you would have to read the contents of the directory it creates to discover and read each section.

The XML Schemas (as @Paul Way states above) are available in the SDK. If you build C# classes from these - using xsd.exe in VS - you could (after unzipping the file) load the XML into a strongly-typed classes. This would get you close to what you want - but not exactly.

You want to be able to call something similar to `var solution = CRMSolutionTool.LoadPackage(@"mysolution.zip")` and then execute a `foreach (var item in solution.entities){}`. Unfortunately, no one has built such a library at this time.